# UITableView in ChildView launch UITableView in ParentView

Tags: swift

I have two `ViewController` with a `UITableView` in each view with the delegates and datasources added.

When I'm in the second view and I scrolled up the table view the event `cellForRowAt` from the parent is called. Why is that possible? and how to avoid it?

Here is the code from the first view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var dataTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        dataTable.delegate = self
        dataTable.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        20
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "firstCell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row)
    
        return cell
    }
}
```

[image]

If I select any row it shows the `SecondViewController`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let secondSB = UIStoryboard(name: "Second", bundle: nil)
    let secondVC = secondSB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second")
    let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
    nc.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic
    
    present(nc, animated: true)
}
```

**Note:** The presentation must be as card because I need it and not `.fullScreen`

The code for the second view controller:

```
class SecondVC: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var dataTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        dataTable.delegate = self
        dataTable.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "firstCell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Second" +  String(indexPath.row)
    
        return cell
    }

}
```

[image]

When I scroll up in the second data table, the event `cellForRowAt` from parent `TableView` is called (Added a breakpoint):

[image]

Another thing is the event `numberOfRowsInSection` is not called, only `cellForRowAt` in the Parent.

I also tried with different table view names but I have the same result.

**Video demo**

[image]

Comment: I don't know the specific reason why this is happening in this particular case, but in general: you should write your code so it does not matter. That means these methods should be pure functions. E.g. You shouldn't add loading logic in `numberOfRowsInSection`, with the assumption that it would be called before `cellForRowAt`. Another example, you shouldn't expect `cellForRowAt` to be called once for every cell. This bit a lot of people when they added off-screen rendering several years back.

Comment: If I show the second view controller as card it means the debugger is not capable to know which view is active? Both tables are different and is strange if I'm using the child table why the parent is active?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but kinda by definition of a "card", both views are "active". They're both (at least partially) visible on-screen. Could you elaborate more on what your actual underlying issue is?

Comment: I'm not showing the second view in full screen, it shows `.automatic' as "card" or I don't know how to say. As active I mean all the events in that view must be called right? Why is called an event from the parent view if you are not using it?

Comment: "Why is called an event from the parent view if you are not using it?" As I said, I don't know, but you're kind of missing my point. The framework (for some reason or another, might be a bug, but it's probably not) thinks that it needs a cell for a table, and is asking for it. My point is: what exactly is the issue? The framework is rendering something in the background, but what harm is coming from that?

Comment: My guess would be that the animation that shrinks/moves the background VC is causing it to invalidate the view, and rerendering the table involves hitting some of the delegate callbacks once more. But again, that's just a guess, and it shouldn't matter, unless this is causing some other issue in your system. That's what I'm trying to find out: this might be surprising, sure, but what actual issue is this causing?

Comment: You have a `var optionSelected = 1` and the row counts from Api is 10. In the second view you can change the `optionSelected` to 2 because is global and rows count from that option is 20. As the parent method is called if you have `data[indexPath.row]` it crashes because the number rows were 10 and now is 20. The parent is getting the row count from the child.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255601/discussion-between-alexander-and-eric).